# Custom field in Woocommerce Single Product tab

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

Hi I am using this Woocommerce Plugin in my site. And what I want is to display my custom fields in single product.

[image]

I know I have to use hooks for this, but have no idea at all what hook to use. Inside woocommerce template I found out `tabs.php` file.

**Here's the code**

```
$tabs = apply_filters( 'woocommerce_product_tabs', array() );

if ( ! empty( $tabs ) ) : ?>

<div class="woocommerce-tabs wc-tabs-wrapper">
    <ul class="tabs wc-tabs">
        <?php foreach ( $tabs as $key => $tab ) : ?>
            <li class="<?php echo esc_attr( $key ); ?>_tab">
                <a href="#tab-<?php echo esc_attr( $key ); ?>"><?php echo apply_filters( 'woocommerce_product_' . $key . '_tab_title', esc_html( $tab['title'] ), $key ); ?></a>
            </li>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
    </ul>
    <?php foreach ( $tabs as $key => $tab ) : ?>
        <div class="panel entry-content wc-tab" id="tab-<?php echo esc_attr( $key ); ?>">
            <?php call_user_func( $tab['callback'], $key, $tab ); ?>
        </div>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
</div>
```

Can anyone help me?

Comment: you need to provide more details... like how are you adding the custom fields... how you want it to display?  include also what have you tried so far...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Copy `wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/templates/single-product/tabs/description.php` to `wp-content/themes/[active theme]/woocommerce/single-product/tabs/description.php`

Create folders if required, now edit the file and add the logic to display your custom fields.

Comment: Tried that, I want to display  a function but it's showing errors.

Comment: Provide details about the custom fields, how have you defined them or are you using a plugin.

Answer (score 2):

Try this one.

Add a hook in functions.php file `add_action( 'woocommerce_after_single_product_summary', 'action_woocommerce_after_single_product_summary', 10, 2 );`

> This function is used to show custom values in description tab
>   Then print the custom field as per you requirement.

```
// define the woocommerce_after_single_product_summary callback 
function action_woocommerce_after_single_product_summary( $woocommerce_output_product_data_tabs, $int ) { 
    // if you have defined custom post type
    echo get_post_meta( $post_id, $key, $single );

    // OR 
    // if you are using acf
    echo $field = get_field($field_name, $post_id, $format_value);
}; 

// add the action 
add_action( 'woocommerce_after_single_product_summary', 'action_woocommerce_after_single_product_summary', 10, 2 );
```